# Создание шкал рейтинга в процентном соотношении

Tags: html, php

Всем привет!

Не могу понять как реализовать.

Есть новости, за которые можно ставить рейтинг от 1 до 5
Хочу вывести шкалы по голосам.
Т.е. примерно так

```
5 ------------- 158 голосов
4 -------- 78 голосов
3 ---------- 90 голосов
2 --- 20 голосов
1 ---------------------- 200 голосов
```

Получаю все в массиве
array(5, 3, 4, 5, 1...)

В html думаю просто

```
<div style="width:тут процент;"></div>
```

Может кто делал уже подобное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просуммировать все голоса: 158+78+90+20+200=546

Посчитать проценты (546/100 = 5.46 далее количество голосов делим на 5.46):

158 голосов - 28.93%

78 голосов - 14.28%

90 голосов - 16.48%

20 голосов - 3.63%

200 голосов - 36.63%

Правда php тут нет, это обычная математика.

Comment: Я понял. Спасибо. Сейчас буду пробовать!

Comment: Например, [так можно](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2yk-jf6)

Comment: Deonis, это немного не то. Шакала 5 бальная.
в массиве может быть либо от 1 до 5. и вот уже на основе этого делать.

Answer (score 0):

Делал - примерно так же, только ширину указывал абсолютную, в px.
Нужно определить макс. ширину баров, и минимальную.
Потом найти максимальный бар из серии, и исходя из этого получить k масштабирования.

Что-то типа:

```
$rating = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$maxWidth = 120; // макс ширина бара - 120 точек
$minWidth = 2;   // мин. ширина бара

$k = $maxWidth / max( $rating);  // надо ещё проверку на 0 добавить!
$tmpl = '<div class="bar" style="width:%dpx;"></div>';
foreach( $rating AS $r){
    printf( $tmpl, max( $minWidth, round( $k * $r)));
}
```

**II вариант, люксовый**

Отрисовывать бары в SVG динамически, c помощью JS. Тогда от PHP потребуется выводить сами данные в JSON, а дальше график отрисуется уже на стороне клиента. Может помочь напр. JS библиотека для работы с SVG "[Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)"